# sed regex is replacing an entire file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have `hdfs-site.xml` file which contains following information

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/data/dfs/nn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/data/dfs/dn,/mnt_test_volume/data/dfs/dn,/mnt_test_volume/data/dfs/dni,/mnt_test_v5olume/data/dfs/dn,/mnt_test_volume/d5ata/dfs/dgn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I want to remove some of the entries present in `<name>dfs.data.dir</name><value>` and `</value></name>` tags. Which entry to remove is decided by one parameter to shell script.

I am new to `sed` and I have written following `sed` command to find particular entry and delete it. This works as expected when `sed` is executed very first time but when same command is executed next time, all the contents of the file are wiped out and file becomes a blank file.

```
sed -ni '1h; 1!H; ${g; s#\(<name>dfs\.data\.dir<\/name>[^a-zA-Z0-9]*<value>.*\)'$data_dir_path'[^,<]\(.*<\/value>\)#\1\2# p}' hdfs-site.xml
```

In this command `$data_dir_path` variable decides which entry to be deleted.

For example, if value of `data_dir_path` is `/mnt_test_volume/data/dfs/dn` then I am expecting following output

```
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>          <value>/data/dfs/dn,,/mnt_test_volume/data/dfs/dni,/mnt_test_v5olume/data/dfs/dn,/mnt_test_volume/d5ata/dfs/dgn</value>
```

which is working fine when command is executed once but if same command is executed next time, entire file becomes empty.

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `sed` is not the right tool for manipulating XML

Comment: use `awk` to identify and replace particular expression.

Comment: @anubhava, What is the proper tool to manipulate XML in shell script? I am new to shell scripting so I don't really know proper tool for this.

Comment: PHP, Perl, Python etc are better equipped to handle this and are readily available with various Unix distros.

Comment: (`$data_dir_path'`) `[^,<]\(.*<` is a bit strange. Take everything but `,`or `<` followed by take everithing than a `<`. at least the `.*` is `[^<]*` in this context and the first `,` if there is one will certainly be too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a much simpler `sed` as

```
  sed "/<name>dfs.data.dir<\/name>/ {n; s#$data_dir_path##}" hdfs-site.xml
```

**What it does?**

- `-i` inplace editing of the file
- `'/<name>dfs.data.dir<\/name>/` checks if the line matches the pattern. If yes then the commands following are excecuted. Note that the commands following are grouped in `{}` as `{n; s/'$data_dir_path'//}'`
- `n;` reads the next line from file into the pattern space
- `s/'$data_dir_path'//` substiture the value in `$data_dir_path` with `null`

**Test**

```
$  sed "/<name>dfs.data.dir<\/name>/ {n; s#$data_dir_path##}" test

bash-3.2$ cat test
:
:
:
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/data/dfs/dn,,i,/mnt_test_v5olume/data/dfs/dn,/mnt_test_volume/d5ata/dfs/dgn</value>
:
:
:
```

Comment: Thanks for  your help. I executed your command but I am getting "sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unknown option to `s'" error.

Comment: @Shekhar are you sure you copy pasted the script correctly. Because it works fine on my system :/

Comment: Yes I copy-pasted command as it is. Somewhere I read that sed behavior changes according to type of shell used (bash, dash, etc.)   Am I getting this error because of shell differences? or sed version mismatch perhaps?

Comment: Problem solved. It was something related to forward slashes. I replaces forward slashes with # and same command worked like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Shekhar its because the variable also contains `/` use ` sed "/<name>dfs.data.dir<\/name>/ {n; s#$data_dir_path##}"` test
instead. Sorry for that will edit the answer